# odd even columns in expressionengine with bootstrap

Tags: grid, switch, bootstrap

I have an issue with looping output for a channel with Bootstrap. What I want to archive is this:

row
col 8 col 4

row 
col 4 col 4 col 4

row
col 8 col 4

row 
col 4 col 4 col 4

and so on. This would be for a blog index page listing all the posts. What I'm looking for is a way to output with the 8 and 4 columns in one row. Its an issue of getting the 8 and 4 columns to have separate posts. Could I use 'switch'? I would like to do this without any plugins.

I can loop the col 4 easy without an issue. Simple code below:

```
<!-- Journal Section -->
<section>
    <div>
        <!-- /.container -->
        <div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            {exp:channel:entries}
            <!-- .col-8 -->
            <div class="wrap col-lg-8 col-sm-12 content-item">
                <a href="{title_permalink=journal/notes}">
                    <img src="{journal_lead_image}{image:url:journal-lead-landscape}{/journal_lead_image}" alt=""
                        title="">
                </a>
                <div class="content_meta">
                    <h5><a href="{title_permalink=journal/notes}">{title}</a></h5>
                </div>
                <p class="item_summary">{journal_summary.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-8 -->

            <!-- .col-4 -->
            <div class="wrap col-lg-4 col-sm-12 content-item">
                <a href="{title_permalink=journal/notes}">
                    <img src="{journal_lead_image}{image:url:journal-lead-portrait}{/journal_lead_image}" alt=""
                        title="">
                </a>
                <div class="content_meta">
                    <h5><a href="{title_permalink=journal/notes}">{title}</a></h5>
                </div>
                <p class="item_summary">{journal_summary}</p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-4 -->
            {/exp:channel:entries}
        </div> <!-- /.row -->
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</section>
<!-- Journal Section -->
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running EE 5.3.2 and the text is pulling in using rich text field. The image tage is using 'channel images. All works fine from that end. 

This did work for creating odd and even rows. However what I what and now works is the second answer:

<div class="{switch="col-lg-4|col-lg-8|col-lg-4|col-lg-4"} wrap col-sm-12 content-item">

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could use switch also.

```
{exp:channel:entries}
  <div class="wrap {switch='col-lg-4|col-lg-8'} col-sm-12 content-item">
    ...
  </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Would output alternating containers with the correct col-lg class:

```
<div class="wrap col-lg-4 col-sm-12 content-item">
  ...
</div>
<div class="wrap col-lg-8 col-sm-12 content-item">
  ..
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'm running EE 5.3.2.

You answer was what I was looking for: 

<div class="{switch="col-lg-4|col-lg-8|col-lg-4|col-lg-4"} wrap col-sm-12 content-item">

This now loops, so that each *col* has a different post which loops to the next *col* and so on down the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a method that allows you to alternate between two row layouts while processing the output of a `channel:entries` tag.

One way to do this is to make use of EE's internal counter, and its conditional processing options - in particular the [modulus operator](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#modulus-operator).

Construct the template code for the two alternate rows and then put them into your template using a structure like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries... }
{if count % 2 == 1} 

... do stuff for the first row type ... 

{if:else}

... do stuff for the second row type ...

{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

That's it.

`count` is a variable that counts up loops within the output of the `channel:entries` tag.

The modulus operation `count % 2` returns 1 on the first and every subsequent 'odd' row, and 0 on every 'even' row.

HTH

*NB.  In general it helps if you can provide some basic information about your EE setup - in particular what version of EE you are using; doing so will make it easier for others to give you appropriate suggestions.*